# Why is my strcasecmp function bringing error messages? (c)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

I'm working on cs50 pset5 speller, and right now I'm on the check function. I use `strcasecmp` to compare two strings case insensitively. I'm coding in cs50 Ide(The one they give us in pset1) and my `strcasecmp` function brings this error message:

```c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
dictionary.c:37:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'strcasecmp' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       i = strcasecmp(word, cursor -> word);
           ^
1 error generated.
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'speller' failed
make: *** [speller] Error 1
```

Here is my code for the check function:

```c
bool check(const char *word)
{ 
    unsigned int lol = hash(word);
     // TODO
   int i;
   node *cursor =table[lol];;
    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
     
       i = strcasecmp(word, cursor -> word);
      if(i == 0)
      {
          return true;
      }
      cursor = cursor->next;
   
    }
    
    
    return false;
}
```

And I included these headers:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
```

Please help me find my problem. I know it's in the `strcasecmp` function, but I don't know where. If anyone has any ideas, PLEASE tell me. I've been stuck on speller for weeks. Thanks.

Comment: `strcasecmp` is not a standard C function, although it does exist on some systems. On other systems, it's called `stricmp`. Either way, you need to find the documentation for the function, and determine what header file you need to include.

Comment: Did you post an [mcve]?  As has been pointed out, you seem to be missing an `#include`, but it's not clear you posted all of the relevant code.

Comment: But does the `stricmp` function compare strings case insensitively?

Comment: That's what the 'i' stands for.

Comment: Are you trying to use a cs50 function?  The problem with these cs50 questions, is that particular coarse encourages students to use non-standard functions where standard functions exist.

Comment: I tried using stricmp but it printed the same error message. I'm totally confused. I'll ad my #include into my question.

Comment: It says I have to include string.h, which I already included.

Comment: You wrote "And I included these libraries:". This is not true. None of these are libraries. They are header files. That is something totally different than a library.

Comment: Your question title mentiones "My strcasecmp". Is it your implementation?

Comment: no it's not my inplementation it just means I'm the one using it

Comment: `#include <strings.h>` (with `s`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [POSIX 7 `strcasecmp()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <strings.h>  <==== NOTE the second "s"
>
> int strcasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```

The proper `#include` for `strcasecmp()` is `strings.h`, not `string.h`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't spot that last s. I added the `#include <strings.h>` header and it totally worked. Thanks. :)